# Is there any way to convert oracle data files from Chinese Simplified (HZ) encoding to Unicode(UTF-8) encoding

Tags: oracle

anyone have any idea?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Are you trying to change the character set of a database?  Move data from one database to another?  Something else?

Comment: I am trying to move data from one oracle database to another oracle database

Comment: The NLS settings is different from both machines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the NLS settings on both machines are correct and that the data on the source is properly encoded, since you are just trying to move data from one database to another, just about any Oracle tool should work.  You could use the export and import utilities (classic or DataPump versions depending on the version of Oracle).  You could also use Streams or materialized views to copy the data from one database to another.  Or you could set up a database link and query data over the database link.  The Oracle client will automatically convert the data from the source character set to the destination character set.